# onchange event not properly calling function

Tags: javascript, html, dom, onchange

I made a select box, and I want to be able to see what is currectly selected from the options. To achieve this, I used the onchange event, so that I could retrieve the currently selected item. When I do:

`<select id  = "choose" onchange = "embed()">
function embed(){}`

I get the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: embed is not defined

What is the cause of this error, and how could I fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Yes, I showed a snippet of the HTML and the javascript that's erroring

Comment: No, that's not a verifiable example.

Comment: That should be all that's needed to debug ^^

Comment: Then why haven't you debugged? It's not enough because your JavaScript isn't in a script tag or external file, just plopped in the HTML...

Comment: Your question will be closed because it's unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should look like:

```
<select id="choose" onchange="embed(this.value)">
<script>
function embed(value){}
</script>
```